# Disable Content Security Policy in JSP/Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, content-security-policy

Within my **view.jsp** file I'm using the "object"-tag to link to another page. It's looks like:

```
<object
 data="https://thisIsAnExample"
 height="540" style="overflow: hidden;" type="text/html" width="960">
</object>
```

But when invoking the view it says:

> Blockt from the Content Security Policy.

I already tried to add some meta data in the head of the .jsp file like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="object-src 'https:/thisIsAnExample';">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="sandbox">
```

But nothing works!
 Are there any recommendations?
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`<meta http-equiv>` doesn't affect CSP when there's a *Content-Security-Policy* header by design.  If it did, then an attacker who could inject content could override the Content-Security-Policy and inject a script.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41345974/20394

You'll have to modify the code that generates the `Content-Security-Policy` header to add an [*object-src*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/object-src) like

```
object-src https://thisIsAnExample;
```

Note that quotes are not required.

If there's a security specialist on your team, talk to them.